How would you improve the landing gear in the WW2-era Spitfire?
I've read that the last improvement done to the landing gear was the shock absorber, but what else could be changed as an improvement?

Welcome, and your English is fine.  I'm curious why you think it needs to be improved though.  Were there problems with it?

@MichaelHall , Thank you!  It's not that I think there's a problem with it in general. But there have been many technological advances since those times, like the materials that are used; it was sharp tech back then. It's one of my favorite aircrafts but I'm not very familiar with it, I only know what I've read online. If you could recommend any articles about the Spitfire for me to read, I would be grateful!

The main problem with the Spitfire's gear was the tire track was very narrow, which made it easy to tip over while turning, especially once slowed down to where the ailerons were ineffective. This was structurally advantageous, because the wing didn't have to take landing loads, the gear being attached at the wing roots, but there was a price in handling (the Me 109 suffered the same problem for the same reasons, and was reputed to be even more exciting than the Spitfire with a very high rate of losses from takeoff and landing accidents).
The main fix to improve the gear would be to do what most other later WW2 fighters did, which is move the gear legs outboard on the wings to improve its ground handling by making the airplane resistant to tipping on a wing tip if the plane swings too hard. This is heavier structurally though, but worth the price because of the reduced ground loop accidents.

Would it be a half way substitute to make the landing wheels wider apart but maintain the mount point in the wing root?  That would give a wider track at the cost of longer legs, posititoned at an angle and needing cross bracing or more strength.

You could, but you would want to cant the wheels to keep them vertical, and this increases the vertical space required to enclose them when retracted. The Me109 splayed the gear like that, but kept the wheel axis perpendicular to the  gear leg, so the wheels roll while tilted inboard 10 of 15 degrees. The result is each wheel wants to roll in a circle toward the opposite side (like a turning bicycle). When weight is transferred to a given wheel during a swing, that wheel wants to turn toward the opposite side amplifying the swing. That's what made the 109 so hairy when rolling on the ground.
